# Insert en SQL campos not null

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, insert

Hola tengo la siguiente duda. Es algo muy básico pero que ahora me tiene varado  . Quiero hacr un query a una tabla desde sql server managment. El problema es que tengo el Id que resulta ser primary key, not null  y supone ser auto incrementable.
Esto querría decir que no puedo insertar un dato directamente y que debería que "auto incrementarse" , pero cuando hago el query simplemente me dice que no puedo dejar el campo de Id como null. Hasta ahora he trato de hacer el query sin inculir el campo Id pero no me lo permite, tampoco me permite meter un valor en el query ni declarar el valor como Null. Alguna idea de que estoy haciendo mal?
Aquí esta la información general

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por ultimo por si no lo ven aquí les dejo mi query, donde estoy despreciando Id

```js
INSERT INTO [DB_PCC].[dbo].[Requests]
           ([Wiw],[UserId],[Project],[SchemeId],[Status],
           [ExpirationDays],[Comments],[DepartmentId]
           ,[CategoryId],[seen],[Light],[Edit],[CreateDate],
           [SeenDate],[SendDate],[AnswerDate]
           ,[EditDate],[Sent],[Approved],[Rejected])
     VALUES
          ('x',3333,'testxxx',2,'En espera',3,'none'
         ,2 ,4,0,1,0,'none' ,'none'
            ,'none' ,'none','none',0,0,0)
GO
```

Comment: mejor sería ver el script de creación de la tabla. Que una columna sea llave, no significa automáticamente que es autoincremental

Comment: [Creo que esto te puede ser de ayuda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013313/why-is-sql-server-throwing-this-error-cannot-insert-the-value-null-into-column)

Comment: @Riddick me sirivió, muchas gracias :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías copiarnos el Query de creación de la tabla para ver como estas declarando la primary key y si es o no autoincrementable.
Por otra parte al insertar en la tabla un nuevo valor de ID y este se repite te da el error que propones.

Comment: Pues encontré que no era autoincrementable, desgraciadamente si quiero cambiar ese parametro debo tubar la tabla y como esta dentro de una base muy grande y tienen muchas relaciones, viviré la resignación :)

Comment: Si las Relaciones son dependientes exclusivamente de esta primary Key y a su vez debe ser auto incrementable, te recomiendo utilizar el diagramador de MSSQL en el puedes editar dependiendo de si las tablas son Catálogos o UDC(Universal Data Collection) si no poseen datos puedes utilizar las modalidades de la sentencia Alter table, para realizar el IDENTITY(1,1) a la coulumna primary key de lo contrario deberas siempre respaldar un Query de creación de la estructura de tablas para evitar estos inconvenientes, suerte.